# Acid-reflux safe breath fresheners?

Tags: gerd-acid-reflux, halitosis-bad-breath, breath-freshners, spearmint

I like my breath to feel clean after meals and have been chewing gums or using mints for years. While I knew that mint itself is bad for gastritis, I only recently heard that chewing gum is troublesome as well.

What are some options for freshening breath after meals for people that having trouble with acid-reflux?

Please note that [general practices to prevent long-term bad breath](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3310/is-there-a-cure-for-bad-breath) may not be relevant.

Comment: Are you looking for something that is portable?  Is that the main concern, as there are obvious options like brushing and I assume a reason that isn't mentioned?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. Portability is a implicit and fundamental requirement for the question. Maybe there are brushing options that are relevant here. I hadn't thought to look them up.

Comment: This is an excellent question! Yes mint can relax the lower esophageal sphincter whether gum or candy form, contributing to reflux. I have looked some into this and have not found good written/internet resources yet, but have spoken with faculty physicians.   Recommendations included drinking sufficient water, following GERD recommendations (as your reflux can contribute to bad breath) including sufficient fruits/vegetables, brushing your tongue, and general oral hygiene. I'm not writing this as an answer because I don't have written resources for it, but will look.